# ERROR in Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

Tags: angular, serve

When I run ng serve , I get the following error

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 673 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 518 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 2.31 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 341 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-02-20T13:02:31.697Z - Hash: 338163632aa756e7ed60 - Time: 29669ms
ERROR in Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
```

I have tried so many things like  npm update,    ng build. But nothing is working.
I get the following message on the browser,
Cannot GET /

---

Executing ng --version 
gives the following output

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.3
Node: 10.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.3
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.3
@angular/cdk                      9.0.1
@angular/cli                      9.0.3
@angular/http                     7.2.16
@angular/material                 9.0.1
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.3
@schematics/angular               9.0.3
@schematics/update                0.900.3
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.6
```

Pl help

Regards,

Comment: Does this solve your problem: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35021#issuecomment-584072502

Comment: for version 9.1.5 see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36993#issue-614461757